# Redirect to a action without changing the URL with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Is there a way to change the control of an Action and pass it to another Action without changing the URL?

```
public virtual ActionResult Mobile(bool redirectToPc = false)
{
    if (redirectToPc)
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "PC");

    return View();
}
```

I want to stay in the URL www.company.com/Mobile even if I am redirected to Action PC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RedirectToAction to different controller without changing URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145339/redirecttoaction-to-different-controller-without-changing-url)

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to make use of URL Rewriting, have a look at Scott Gu's blogpost [Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net). The idea is to perform the redirection while manipulating the URI to pretend you remained on the same page.

Example:

```
if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Products/Books.aspx")) {
    Context.RewritePath("/Products.aspx?Category=Books");
}
```

But please don't do it yourself, look the part about UrlRewriter.net and UrlRewriting.net carefully.