# Redirect one Controller To another controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I Have Two Controller `Customer_Infocontroller` and another `Order_Infocontroller` . Right Now I Am In `Customer_Infocontroller` . I Want To view `Order_Infocontrolle`r without Route Change . Only Use Link Tag How it Possible .Please Help Me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RedirectToAction to different controller without changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145339/redirecttoaction-to-different-controller-without-changing-url)

Comment: you can try `return RedirectToAction("Order_Infocontroller")`, this works to Redirect to an `Action` you can also pass parameters.

Comment: Use `RedirectToAction` and `RedirectToRoute` with caution. This causes the server to send an HTTP 302 response to the browser telling it to lookup a new location on the server. You should only use them when you want the URL to change in the browser. If you want to send the user somewhere else *without* a URL change, you should change your routing or programatically change the route values before the controller is instantiated.